# processing sequential and parallel jobs in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I understand that in bash programming, `comamnd1;command2;command3` will run them sequentially while `command1&&command2&&command3` will run them in parallel. However what happens when I combine `;` and `&&` together, e.g. `command1 ; command2 && command 3`?
What is precedence between `;` and `&&` in bash? Is above command equivalent 
to  `(command1;commmand2) && command3` or 
to  `(command1);(command2 && command3)`

Comment: You are mistaken, `&&` will not cause the commands to run in parallel. It will run them sequentially as `;` with the difference that the seconds command will be executed only if the first one returns `0` exit status. This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing: to run a command in the background you type it followed by a single `&` ,  the double `&&` is a *logical and* operator (as well as `||` is logical or).
Running `command1 && command2` returns *logical true* (i.e. return code 0,  which means "no error") if both commands return without error.
As a much used side effect,  command2 is not executed when command1 has returned an error,  since the result of the logical and operation cannot yield true if the first argument is already known to be false.

```
command1 ; command2 & command3
```

Commands are executed left to right: first `command1` is run,  waited until it has finished,  then `command2` is run in the background (as it is followed by `&`) and immediately followed by `command3`.

You can use braces to let a sequence of commands be run in the background like this:

```
{ command1 ; command2 ; } & command3
```

Comment: Note: in your first command line, I believe you mean `command2` to be the second entry.  (I'd have done an edit, but they must be at least 6 characters, so...)

Comment: You are right, thanks to [mpy](https://superuser.com/users/195224/mpy) for correcting this.